# I cannot send keystrokes to a selected input box

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"path to program" ')
afx = app[u'Afx:01360000:0']
afx.Wait('ready')
afxtoolbar = afx[u'1']
toolbar_button = afxtoolbar.Button(3)
toolbar_button.Click()

window = app.Dialog
window.Wait('ready')
edit = window.Edit4
edit.Click()

app.typekeys ("Success")
```

So at this point, I've gotten the application to open, the correct window to pop up and also a mouse click on the box that I want to populate with a short string. I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to pass keyboard input to this field. I have read all the docs for PyWinAuto, and nothing is helping...

Basically all I need to do is figure out how to send a string, and then how to send the TAB key six times. I can then finish my program to automate this application.

I am also using Swapy64bit to help. The program uses a win32 backend. I'm using Python 3.6.

Am I not prefixing typekeys correctly? The PyWinAuto documentation leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

First the correct name of the method is `type_keys`, but assume you use it correctly.

The reason might be losing focus at the edit control because `type_keys` tries to set focus automatically. The solution is:

```
app.type_keys("Success{TAB 6}", set_foreground=True)
```